# Installing Haskell on Ubuntu 12

Tags: haskell, ubuntu

I skimmed some tutorials about installing Haskell on Ubuntu. They basically told about Ubuntu 11 and mentioned that it took a lot of effort. I found nothing about installing Haskell on Ubuntu 12.

Is there any tutorial or something about how to do it? Is there an installer for Ubuntu 12 x64?

Comment: It's usually a safe bet that, for any pair or good operating system and major (open) software project, the package database/manager will do the job for you.  It's rather shocking that as recently as 11.xx someone had significant issues.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I think

`sudo aptitude install haskell-platform`

should do the trick.

On second thoughts, if you do not have `aptitude` installed, you can do the same with

`sudo apt-get install haskell-platform`

From there, you can access the REPL by invoking `ghci` from the command line.

Comment: Right you are, [hp on ubunutu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/haskell-platform).

Comment: no luck: E: Unable to locate package haskell- (on raring ringtail 13.04)

Comment: Interesting error message... Was there a space after the hyphen in the command you entered?

Comment: @opensas Haskell platform is not supported because 13.04 shipped with GHC 7.6.2 [look here for more info](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286764/how-to-install-haskell-platform-for-ubuntu-13-04)

Answer (score 7):

On Ubuntu 13.04, I had to do the following and I wanted to install herbalizer haml -> erb converter.

```
sudo apt-get install ghc6 ghc6-prof ghc6-doc cabal-install
cabal update
cabal install herbalizer
sudo ln ~/.cabal/bin/herbalizer /usr/bin/herbalizer
```

Comment: @TimStewart Because they hate functional programming ;)

Comment: I deleted the link I provided because the linked to content is now gone.

Answer (score 1):

Well all you need to run Haskell is to install GHCI by typing these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install ghc-ghci
```

Now you can run it by writing **ghci** in your terminal. You can compile your files by the  following command once in the ghci prompt:

```
:load File
```

Hope this will help